# InputFormTextBox not supported in SharePoint 2010 sandboxed solutions

Tags: sharepoint-2010, web-parts, sandbox-solution

I'm trying to build a sandboxed solution visual webpart that includes a richtext field, the inputformtextbox control, and it looks like the better part of the Microsoft.SharePoint.Webcontrols namespace isn't available in sandboxed solution? Is this true? Has anyone come across a workaround for this?

Comment: Yes, Microsoft.SharePoint.Webcontrols is not available in sandboxed solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a workaround, the Ajax libraries have a Richtext editor.